# create array using numpy for-loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

Ok, so i have wrapped a C library in Python and called the corresponding DLL's
then i created a for loop that prints out all 60,000 data points which then crashes Python.

## This is my question:

How can I create a for loop in numpy so it is faster and doesn't crash python?

Here is a small sample of the C library that i have wrapped and the dll that i'm calling:

```
import ctypes 
from ctypes import * 

class SParm(Structure):
pass

SParm._fields_ = [
        ('name', ctypes.c_char_p),
        ('time', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),  

dll.readSParm.argtypes = (POINTER(SFile), c_char_p, c_double, c_double,    c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,)   
dll.readSParm.restype = POINTER(SParm)

g = dll.readSParm(SF, ParmName, startTime, stopTime, Null, None, convertType)
```

This is Python for-loop that I have created.

```
time = (g[0].time)
for i in (time):
print(i)
```

^ this prints out values and then crashes python before its finished

I was trying something like this:

```
time = (g[0].time)
for i in (time):
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, i)
```

but the code above throws this error at me:

```
ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: The `for` loop shouldn't crash python, even if there are a lot of data points. I'm rather guessing that you have some kind of memory access problem, but it's hard to know without seeing your C code. Did you try with a smaller amount of data points (10 maybe) ? What is the actual error you get when python crashes in your original `for` loop?

Comment: I don't have the data so I cant try only 10 data points. `time = (g[0].time)` is a pointer to where the data is stored. I was trying to make python print out all of the values for me but that ends up making it crash. When Python crashes I don't get an error code. A box pops up and says "Python has stopped working, a problem caused this, please close the program" @ThomasKuhn

Comment: @ThomasKühn is there maybe a way to end the loop after it gives me the last data point?

Comment: Well, if you know the exact length, then yes.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Yes, I know the exact length. How would I go about ending the loop?

Comment: Is `g[0].time' indexable or is it a generator (i.e what does `time[0]` give you and what does `next(time)` give you)?

Comment: With this input: `print(g[0].time[0]) print(g[0].time[1])` I receive this as an output:  `-1031.0762939453125   -1031.0362548828125`  those I believe are the first two data points. @ThomasKühn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not work on the first try, but I'll edit the question as we go along. Try to alter your `for`-loop in this way:

```
for i in range(N):
   print(i, g[0].time[i])
```

Here `N` is the exact amount of data points that you said you know. The idea of printing also `i` is that if the program still crashes, we will get an idea at which point it does so.

Comment: That worked! It prints out all the data points and doesn't crash Python.

Comment: If you are satisfied you may accept the answer, so that others know that you don't require any further help. Apparently you have some problem in your dll -- it appears to not handle the list length properly.